# Capture refresh in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I know that there is a function called `onStop` which triggers when the application stops. Similar to this is there a function which captures when the users starts refreshing?

```
 server = function(input, output, session) {
      Sys.sleep(10)
      print(Sys.time())
      onStop(function() print(Sys.time()))
    },
```

Comment: What do you mean with "starts refreshing"?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a callback function via `session$onSessionEnded` to detect when a session was closed and this is what happens when the user reloads the page in the browser.

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  session$onSessionEnded(function(){
    cat(sprintf("Session %s was closed\n", session$token))
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui,
  server,
  onStart = function() {
    cat("Doing application setup\n")
    onStop(function() {
      cat("Doing application cleanup\n")
    })
  }
)
```